# Am I missing something in my code that's making it not properly graded?

Tags: processing

My assignment is to approximate Pi in Processing by using the formulas for the areas of a square and a circle.

I have full marks for creating the circle but the only thing that's wrong is the Pi approximation. But I don't understand why, since my outcome is always hovering around Pi. It is required to print the outcome(s) on one line.

This is getting graded by Codegrade (automatic grading application), so maybe there's something I missed that's making it so that the grading app declares it as wrong.

```
float xM = 200.0;
float yM = 200.0;

void setup()
{
    size(400, 400);
    background(255, 255, 255);
    circle(200, 200, 400);
}

void draw()
{
    float x = random(0.0, 400.0);
    float y = random(0.0, 400.0);
    float radius = sqrt( (xM - x) * (xM - x) + (yM - y) * (yM - y) ); 
    float M = PI * radius * radius;
    float N = 4 * radius * radius;

    if (radius <= 200)
    {
    stroke(0,255,0);
    point(x,y);
    }
    else
    {    
    stroke(255,0,0);
    point(x,y);
    }
    
    float approximation = M / N * 4;
    println(approximation);
}
```

Comment: > It is required to print the outcome(s) on one line.  Try adding 'noLoop();' as the last line in setup().

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not actually approximating PI.
If you look at these lines of code:

```
float M = PI * radius * radius;
float N = 4 * radius * radius;

//...

float approximation = M / N * 4;
```

**M/N * 4** is doing the same as **PI/4 * 4**, which will still be PI ofcourse.
I presume the slight variance you are seeing is a result of a rounding error.

I think what you are looking to do is count up the occurrences of points that fall inside the circle. Then using the the ratio of the area of a circle and a square, approximate PI:

```
int pointsInsideOfCircle = 0;
int totalPoints = 0;

void draw()
{
    float x = random(0.0, 400.0);
    float y = random(0.0, 400.0);
    float radius = sqrt( (xM - x) * (xM - x) + (yM - y) * (yM - y) ); 

    if (radius <= 200)
    {
    stroke(0,255,0);
    point(x,y);
    pointsInsideOfCircle++;
    }
    else
    {    
    stroke(255,0,0);
    point(x,y);
    }
    
    totalPoints++;
    
    //float approximation = M / N * 4;
    // area_of_circle / area_of_square * 4
    float approximation = (float) pointsInsideOfCircle / totalPoints * 4;
    println(approximation);
}
```